# Multiple file uploads issue in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel-5, file-upload, eloquent, multiple-file-upload

I am facing an issue related to multiple files uploads in laravel version 5.7.*

**This is what i have in web.php**

```
Route::get('add/news',[
            'uses' => 'Admin\NewsController@create',
            'as'     => 'add.news'
        ]);
        Route::post('add/news',[
            'uses' => 'Admin\NewsController@store',
            'as'     => 'add.newsProcess'
        ]);
```

**In blade file form code**

```
<form  id="addNewsForm" action = "{{ route('add.newsProcess') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <fieldset>
     <legend>News Management Area</legend>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-form-label" for="news_title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="news_title" class="form-control news_title placeholder-shown" placeholder="News Title" id="news_title"> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label" for="newsBody">Body</label>
        <textarea  name="newsBody" class="form-control newsBody placeholder-shown" id="newsBody"></textarea>
      </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>Attachments <span class="optional">(Optional)</span></label>
        <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" name="newsAttachments[]" class="custom-file-input newsAttachments" id="tf3" multiple>
        <label class="custom-file-label persist" for="tf3">Choose Attachment</label>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <span style="margin-left: -15px;">Status</span>
        <label class="switcher-control" style="margin-right: -12px;">
          <input type="checkbox" name="is_active" class="switcher-input" checked="checked">
          <span class="switcher-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group btn-toggle">
      <button type="submit" id="BtnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>   
</fieldset>
<div id="loader"></div>
</form>
```

**Model Code**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class NewsTb extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey  = 'news_id';
    protected $fillable    = ['title','body','attachment','published_on','is_active','user_id'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

**In my controller i have this code**

```
public function store(Request $request)
   {
    dd($request->all());

    $user_id = Auth::id();
    $news_title    = $request->news_title;
    $newsBody      = $request->newsBody;
    $is_active     = $request->is_active;
    $is_active     = $request->is_active;

    if ($is_active === "on") {
        $is_active = 1;
      }
      else{
          $is_active = 0;
    }

    if($request->hasFile('newsAttachments'))
    {
      foreach($request->file('newsAttachments') as $key => $image)
        {
            print_r($image);
           $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
           $image_encod = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('newsAttachments')[$key]));
           $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
           $image->move($destinationPath, $name);

           /*$data = new Image();
           $data->image_name = $image_encod;
           $data->save();*/

        }   
    }
}
```

**I am facing this issue with multiple files uploads but getting this error.**

> ```
> ErrorException (E_WARNING)
> trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
> ```

**Please help me thanks in advance**

Comment: can you convert your `foreach($request->file('newsAttachments') as $key => $image)` into `foreach($request->file('newsAttachments') as $image)` this and try

Comment: I have already tried that as well but still given the same error .trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.when i dd the request same occurs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this one

foreach($request->file('newsAttachments') as $key => $image)

with this code

foreach($request->file('newsAttachments') as $image)